# Local audio not working in Icecomm

Tags: javascript, audio, webrtc

I'm going through the icecomm webrtc documentation and trying to find how to set local user audios on by default. I can get video working with these lines, but is there an audio parameter for the options?

```
comm.on(‘local’, function(options) {
    localVideo.src = options.stream;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In Icecomm, local audio is turned off by default to eliminate feedback from local audio for video conferencing, but can be accessed by the `rawStream` property of the options parameter in the `comm.on(‘local’, callback)` event handler. Like so:

```
comm.on('local', function(options) {
    localVideo.src = options.rawStream;
});
```